# How to deploy multiple version of the same WAR inside an EAR with different configurations

Tags: java, maven, deployment, war, ear

I'm struggling with this problem:

I have a Maven project A, which is builded as a WAR and should be placed inside an EAR. Now I need to also deploy different "clones" of the same project inside that ear, all with the same logic but:
1- different name;
2- different context;
3- **the possibility for the application itself to know who he is**.

I can address the first two things like that:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                        <displayName>Parent App</displayName>
                        <modules>
                             <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
                                <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
                                <bundleFileName>projectA-1</bundleFileName>
                                <context-root>/ProjectA1</context-root>
                             </webModule>
                             <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
                                <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
                                <bundleFileName>projectA-2</bundleFileName>
                                <context-root>/ProjectA2</context-root>
                             </webModule>
                             <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
                                <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
                                <bundleFileName>projectA-3</bundleFileName>
                                <context-root>/ProjectA3</context-root>
                             </webModule>
                        </modules>
                 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But how can ProjectA1 know that he is the number 1, and ProjectA2 know that he is the number 2, etc? I need to know that inside the code, and I can't place a property file directly inside the ProjectA artifact because it would be the same for every clone. So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Any progress on this one? Tip: you are welcome to answer your own questions ;)